# Apache serves .py as downloadable file instead of executing it

Tags: python, apache-http-server

Ubuntu machine.

Installed mod_python using apt-get.

added

```
   <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all  
            AddHandler mod_python .py
            PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
            PythonDebug On
    </Directory>
```

to the sites-available/default file.

Restarted Apache.

But I still do not see Python running. Instead the browser starts downloading the file.

Comment: Think about using http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/ instead.

Comment: I still have no clue what is wrong with what I am doing. I was wondering if modwsgi has some advangates over mod_python when it comes to installing using Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

```
PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
```

needs to be

```
PythonHandler mod_python.cgihandler
```

Then you can run Python as CGI.

Comment: In my case publisher did work. What i miss is the `from mod_python import apache` on the .py file, otherwise fails. Now i can server python as well. Nice :D